# PHP 7.0.7 hash_equals not working with crypt() or hash()?

Tags: php, variables, hash, equals, crypt

I didnt see much on this even when searching google, google video & this website. Was wondering why this is if I set. Tried to do some tests on this though. Is mostly password_verify that I see though even on videos. wouldnt matter what I use if variable has hash() or crypt() is in it wont work at all.

```
$hash_user_pwd2 = crypt('312132', '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$');

var_dump(hash_equals($row['password1'], '$hash_user_pwd2'));
```

seems error is with the variable only but when I get specific and set variable to '214234243j32k4jj234' works fine i.e.

```
var_dump(hash_equals($row['password1'], '214234243j32k4jj234'));
```

Comment: You pass the string `'$hash_user_pwd2'` rather than variable in the first example.

Comment: Difference between single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes.... and why are you quoting `'$hash_user_pwd2'` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the full `crypt()` as the second param of hash_equals

```
<?php
$hashed_password = crypt('topsecret', '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$');

if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt('topsecret', $hashed_password))) {
   echo "Password verified!";
}
?>
```